# Reloading data on home page android

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

When the Home page of my app is launched it gets all the data from MySQL using "onAsyncTaskDoInBackground" and that takes around 10 seconds. The problem I am having is after the user clicks away from the home page to look at the other pages on the app and then goes back to the home page it deletes all the data and downloads it again wasting another 10 seconds.

So every time the home page is launched the onAsyncTaskDoInBackground loads all the data, what I want to have happen is only when the app is launched and the home page opens it loads all the data and if the user returns to the home page it does not re download everything

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, MainActivity.OnLocationListener {

private View viewInflate;
DisplayImageOptions options;
ArrayList<Store> storeList;
ArrayList<News> newsList;
MGAsyncTask task;
Queries q;
private Store store;
Random rand = new Random();


public HomeFragment() { }

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    return viewInflate;
}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
}



@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .showImageOnFail(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
    newsList = new ArrayList<News>();

    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    timer();
    main.showSwipeProgress();
    main.getDebugKey();

    q = main.getQueries();
    if(MGUtilities.isLocationEnabled(getActivity())) {
        if(MainActivity.location == null) {
            main.setOnLocationListener(this);
        }
        else {
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getData();
                }
            }, Config.DELAY_SHOW_ANIMATION);
        }
    }
    else {
        main.setOnLocationListener(this);
    }
}


public void getData() {
    task = new MGAsyncTask(getActivity());

    task.setMGAsyncTaskListener(new OnMGAsyncTaskListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPreExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            asyncTask.dialog.hide();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPostExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(!MGUtilities.hasConnection(getActivity())) {
                ArrayList<Store> stores = q.getStoresFeatured();
                ArrayList<News> news = q.getNews();
                if (Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT != -1 && Config.RANK_STORES_ACCORDING_TO_NEARBY) {
                    Log.v("myApp", "STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - STORE SLIDER THING - " );

                    int storeCount = stores.size() < Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT ?
                            stores.size() : Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT;

                    if (MainActivity.location != null) {
                        for (Store store : stores) {
                            Location locStore = new Location("Store");
                            locStore.setLatitude(store.getLat());
                            locStore.setLongitude(store.getLon());
                            double userDistanceFromStore = MainActivity.location.distanceTo(locStore) / 1000;
                            store.setDistance(userDistanceFromStore);
                        }

                        Collections.sort(stores, new Comparator<Store>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Store store, Store t1) {
                                if (store.getDistance() < t1.getDistance())
                                    return -1;
                                if (store.getDistance() > t1.getDistance())
                                    return 1;
                                return 0;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
                    for (int x = 0; x < storeCount; x++) {

                        storeList.add(stores.get(x));

                    }
                } else {
                    storeList = stores;
                }

                if (Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT != -1 && Config.RANK_STORES_ACCORDING_TO_NEARBY) {
                    Log.v("myApp", "NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - NEWS SLIDER THING - " );

                    int newsCount = news.size() < Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT ? news.size() : Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT;
                    newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
                    for (int x = 0; x < newsCount; x++) {
                        newsList.add(news.get(x));
                    }
                } else {
                    newsList = news;
                }
            }




            createSlider();


            showList();

            MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            main.hideSwipeProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(MGAsyncTask asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tvTitleHeaderr = (TextView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.all);

            if( MGUtilities.hasConnection(getActivity()) && MainActivity.location != null) {

                try {
                    UserAccessSession accessSession = UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity());
                    String strUrl = "";
                    if(accessSession.getFilterDistance() == 0) {
                        Log.v("myApp", "STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - STRURL - " );
                        if(MGUtilities.hasConnection(getActivity())) {

                            try {

                                strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s",
                                        Config.GET_CATEGORIES_JSON_URL,
                                        Config.API_KEY);

                                DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                                Data data = parser.getData(strUrl);

                                MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                                if (main == null)
                                    return;

                                Queries q = main.getQueries();
                                if (data == null)
                                    return;

                                q.deleteTable("categories");
                                if (data.getCategories() != null && data.getCategories().size() > 0) {
                                    Log.v("myApp", "CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - CATEGORYS - " );

                                    for (Category cat : data.getCategories()) {
                                        q.insertCategory(cat);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s&lat=%f&lon=%f&radius=%f&news_count=%d&featured_count=%d&default_store_count_to_find_distance=%d",
                                Config.GET_HOME_STORES_NEWS_JSON_URL,
                                Config.API_KEY,
                                MainActivity.location.getLatitude(),
                                MainActivity.location.getLongitude(),
                                accessSession.getFilterDistance(),
                                Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT,
                                Config.HOME_FEATURED_COUNT,
                                Config.DEFAULT_STORE_COUNT_TO_FIND_DISTANCE);
                    }
                    else {

                        strUrl = String.format("%s?api_key=%s&lat=%f&lon=%f&radius=%f&news_count=%d&default_store_count_to_find_distance=%d",
                                Config.GET_HOME_STORES_NEWS_JSON_URL,
                                Config.API_KEY,
                                MainActivity.location.getLatitude(),
                                MainActivity.location.getLongitude(),
                                accessSession.getFilterDistance(),
                                Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT,
                                Config.DEFAULT_STORE_COUNT_TO_FIND_DISTANCE);
                    }

                    DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                    Data data = parser.getData(strUrl);
                    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                    if (main == null)
                        return;

                    Queries q = main.getQueries();
                    if (data == null)
                        return;

                    if(Config.AUTO_ADJUST_DISTANCE) {
                        if(data.getMax_distance() > 0) {
                            UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity()).setFilterDistanceMax(data.getMax_distance());
                        }

                        if(UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity()).getFilterDistance() == 0) {
                            UserAccessSession.getInstance(getActivity()).setFilterDistance(data.getDefault_distance());
                        }
                    }



                    if (data.getStores() != null && data.getStores().size() > 0) {

                        Log.v("myApp", "ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF - ENTERED THE IF" );

                        int storeCount = data.getStores().size() < Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT ?
                                data.getStores().size() : Config.HOME_STORE_FEATURED_COUNT;

                        int x = 0;
                        for (Store store : data.getStores()) {
                            Location locStore = new Location("Store");
                            locStore.setLatitude(store.getLat());
                            locStore.setLongitude(store.getLon());
                            double userDistanceFromStore = MainActivity.location.distanceTo(locStore) / 1000;
                            store.setDistance(userDistanceFromStore);
                            if (userDistanceFromStore < 50){
                            Log.v("myApp", "STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE - STORE- STORE" );
                            q.deleteStore(store.getStore_id());
                            q.insertStore(store);


                            if(x < storeCount) {
                                Log.v("myApp", "if(x < storeCount) - if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)- if(x < storeCount)" );

                                if (store.getFeatured() == 3 ) {
                                    storeList.add(store);
                                    x += 1;

                                }


                            }

                            if (store.getPhotos() != null && store.getPhotos().size() > 0) {
                                Log.v("myApp", "PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS - PHOTOS" );
                                for (Photo photo : store.getPhotos()) {
                                    q.deletePhoto(photo.getPhoto_id());
                                    q.insertPhoto(photo);
                                }
                            }
                        }}


                    }

                    if (data.getNews() != null && data.getNews().size() > 0) {
                        Log.v("myApp", "NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS - NEWS" );
                        int newsCount = data.getNews().size() < Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT
                                ? data.getNews().size() : Config.HOME_NEWS_COUNT;

                        int x = 0;
                        for (News news : data.getNews()) {
                            q.deleteNews(news.getNews_id());
                            q.insertNews(news);

                            if(x < newsCount) {
                                newsList.add(news);
                                x += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }
        }
    });
    task.execute();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()  {

    super.onDestroyView();
    if (viewInflate != null) {
        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewInflate.getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null) {
            MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
            slider.pauseSliderAnimation();
            parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
}
Handler handler = new Handler();
int apple = 0;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(apple < 5) {
            timer();
        }
    }
};

public void timer()
{

    int randomNum = 1 + rand.nextInt((50 - 1) + 1);
    TextView tvTitleHeader = (TextView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleeee);
    if (randomNum == 1 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A1));
    }
    if (randomNum == 2 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A2));
    }
    if (randomNum == 3 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A3));
    }
    if (randomNum == 4 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A4));
    }
    if (randomNum == 5 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A5));
    }
    if (randomNum == 6 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A6));
    }
    if (randomNum == 7 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A7));
    }
    if (randomNum == 8 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A8));
    }
    if (randomNum == 9 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A9));
    }
    if (randomNum == 10 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A10));
    }
    if (randomNum == 11 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A11));
    }
    if (randomNum == 12 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A12));
    }
    if (randomNum == 13 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A13));
    }
    if (randomNum == 14 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A14));
    }
    if (randomNum == 15 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A15));
    }
    if (randomNum == 16 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A16));
    }
    if (randomNum == 17 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A17));
    }
    if (randomNum == 18 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A18));
    }
    if (randomNum == 19 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A19));
    }
    if (randomNum == 20 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A20));
    }
    if (randomNum == 21 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A21));
    }
    if (randomNum == 22 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A22));
    }
    if (randomNum == 23 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A23));
    }
    if (randomNum == 24 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A24));
    }
    if (randomNum == 25 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A25));
    }
    if (randomNum == 26 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A26));
    }
    if (randomNum == 27 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A27));
    }
    if (randomNum == 28 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A28));
    }
    if (randomNum == 29 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A29));
    }
    if (randomNum == 30 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A30));
    }
    if (randomNum == 31 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A31));
    }
    if (randomNum == 32 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A32));
    }
    if (randomNum == 33 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A33));
    }
    if (randomNum == 34 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A34));
    }
    if (randomNum == 35 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A35));
    }
    if (randomNum == 36 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A36));
    }
    if (randomNum == 37 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A37));
    }
    if (randomNum == 38 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A38));
    }
    if (randomNum == 39 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A39));
    }
    if (randomNum == 40 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A40));
    }
    if (randomNum == 41 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A41));
    }
    if (randomNum == 42 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A42));
    }
    if (randomNum == 43 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A43));
    }
    if (randomNum == 44 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A44));
    }
    if (randomNum == 45 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A45));
    }
    if (randomNum == 46 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A46));
    }
    if (randomNum == 47 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A47));
    }
    if (randomNum == 48 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A48));
    }
    if (randomNum == 49 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A49));
    }
    if (randomNum == 50 ){
        tvTitleHeader.setText(getString(R.string.A50));
    }


    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
    apple++;
}
private void showList() {
    ListView listView = (ListView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    MGListAdapter adapter = new MGListAdapter(
            getActivity(), newsList.size(), R.layout.twitter_dialog);

    adapter.setOnMGListAdapterAdapterListener(new OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener() {

        @Override
        public void OnMGListAdapterAdapterCreated(MGListAdapter adapter, View v,
                                                  int position, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            News news = newsList.get(position);
            MGImageView imgViewPhoto = (MGImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgViewPhoto);
            imgViewPhoto.setCornerRadius(0.0f);
            imgViewPhoto.setBorderWidth(UIConfig.BORDER_WIDTH);
            imgViewPhoto.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(UIConfig.THEME_BLACK_COLOR));

            if(news.getPhoto_url() != null) {
                MainActivity.getImageLoader().displayImage(news.getPhoto_url(), imgViewPhoto, options);
            }
            else {
                MainActivity.getImageLoader().displayImage(null, imgViewPhoto, options);
            }

            imgViewPhoto.setTag(position);
            Spanned name = Html.fromHtml(news.getNews_title());
            Spanned address = Html.fromHtml(news.getNews_content());

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvTitle.setText(name);

            TextView tvSubtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtitle);
            tvSubtitle.setText(address);

            String date = DateTimeHelper.getStringDateFromTimeStamp(news.getCreated_at(), "MM/dd/yyyy" );
            TextView tvDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            tvDate.setText(date);
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long resId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.stopSliderAnimation();

    News news = newsList.get(pos);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("news", news);
    getActivity().startActivity(i);
}

// Create Slider
private void createSlider() {
    if(storeList != null && storeList.size() == 0 && newsList != null && newsList.size() == 0) {
        MGUtilities.showNotifier(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.offsetY, R.string.failed_data);
        return;

    }

    final MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    final Queries q = main.getQueries();

    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    if (storeList.size() < 1) {
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.framelayout100);
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ImageView layoutt = (ImageView) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.framelayout1001);
        layoutt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    slider.setMaxSliderThumb(storeList.size());
    MGSliderAdapter adapter = new MGSliderAdapter(
            R.layout.slider_entry, storeList.size(), storeList.size());

    adapter.setOnMGSliderAdapterListener(new OnMGSliderAdapterListener() {

        @Override
        public void onOnMGSliderAdapterCreated(MGSliderAdapter adapter, View v,
                                               int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Store entry = storeList.get(position);
            Photo p = q.getPhotoByStoreId(entry.getStore_id());
            ImageView imageViewSlider = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSlider);
            if(p != null) {
                MainActivity.getImageLoader().displayImage(p.getPhoto_url(), imageViewSlider, options);
            }
            else {
                imageViewSlider.setImageResource(UIConfig.SLIDER_PLACEHOLDER);
            }

            imageViewSlider.setTag(position);
            imageViewSlider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("store", entry);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            Spanned name = Html.fromHtml(entry.getStore_name());
            Spanned address = Html.fromHtml(entry.getIdade());
            Spanned hour = Html.fromHtml(entry.getHora());

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvTitle.setText(name);

            TextView tvSubtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtitle);
            tvSubtitle.setText(" "+ address);

            TextView tvHour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHour);
            tvHour.setText(" "+hour);

            TextView tvDistance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
            tvDistance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(MGUtilities.isLocationEnabled(getActivity()) && MainActivity.location != null) {
                if(entry.getDistance() != -1) {
                    tvDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    double miles = entry.getDistance();
                    String format = String.format(
                            "%.2f %s", miles,
                            MGUtilities.getStringFromResource(getActivity(), R.string.km));
                    tvDistance.setText(format);
                }
                else {
                    tvDistance.setText(R.string.empty_distance);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    slider.setOnMGSliderListener(new OnMGSliderListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemThumbSelected(MGSlider slider, ImageView[] buttonPoint,
                                        ImageView imgView, int pos) { }

        @Override
        public void onItemThumbCreated(MGSlider slider, ImageView imgView, int pos) { }


        @Override
        public void onItemPageScrolled(MGSlider slider, ImageView[] buttonPoint, int pos) { }

        @Override
        public void onItemMGSliderToView(MGSlider slider, int pos) { }

        @Override
        public void onItemMGSliderViewClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v,
                                            int pos, long resid) { }

        @Override
        public void onAllItemThumbCreated(MGSlider slider, LinearLayout linearLayout) { }

    });
    slider.setOffscreenPageLimit(storeList.size() - 1);
    slider.setAdapter(adapter);
    slider.setActivity(this.getActivity());
    slider.setSliderAnimation(3000);
    slider.resumeSliderAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.stopSliderAnimation();
    switch(v.getId()) { }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.resumeSliderAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    MGSlider slider = (MGSlider) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    slider.pauseSliderAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location prevLoc, Location currentLoc) {
    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    main.setOnLocationListener(null);
    getData();
}
public static void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(
        final Activity activity)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
    final String message = "Não foi possível localiza-lo."
            + " Por favor habilite seu GPS para encontrar"
            + " as acompanhantes próximas de você.";


    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                            System.exit(0);
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

    builder.create().show();


}
}
```

Comment: For that try calling you Asynctask only when the view is created first  that is onCreateView()

Comment: @IramBukhari did not work :(

Comment: Why not try creating Boolean static calltaskflag = true and make it false as soon as Asynctask is called. Just to make sure Asynctask is loaded only once when the view is first called. :) Let me know if that helps